Sturm-Liouville theory of PDEs
I'm looking for information about the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of boundary value problems of two-dimensional PDEs i.e. Sturm-Liouville problems of the form:
$$
\nabla.(p(x,y)\nabla f(x,y))+q(x,y)f(x,y)=-\lambda w(x,y)f(x,y)
$$
in a 2-d simply connected part of the $(x,y)$ plane, $\Gamma$, say, together with a Dirichlet boundary condition:
$$
f(x,y)=0
$$
on the boundary curve, $\partial\Gamma$ (more general boundary conditions are also of some interest to me, but are of lesser importance). Of particular interest to me is the case $p(x,y)=q(x,y)=w(x,y)=1$. I'm interested in the eigenvalue distributions (including their asymptotics as $\lambda\to\infty$) and the general properties of the corresponding eigenfunctions (e.g. their nodes). However, I can't find anything about such problems in the open literature. All the focus seems to be on the corresponding 1-d problems (e.g. showing non-degeneracy of eigenvalues, orthogonality of corresponding eigenfunctions and their unique number of nodes). Are there any useful general statements that can be made about the 2-d problem?
Thanks in advance for any help.

If $p = q = w = 1$ then the problem reduces to the PDE $$\nabla^{2} f = - \tilde{\lambda} f$$ where $\tilde{\lambda} = \lambda + 1$, which is just the Helmholtz equation for $\tilde{\lambda} > 0$.

The Weyl Conjecture and related topics involve asymptotic estimates of these eigenvalues in terms of geometric properties of the domain
